# How to make SystemJS transpile 'typescript' based on file extension not contents

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I have this SystemJS config in index.html:

```
<body>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true,
                transpiler: 'typescript',
                map: {
                    typescript: 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
                },
                packages: {
                    "ts": {
                        "defaultExtension": "ts"
                    }
                },
            });
            System.import('ts/main');

        </script>
</body>
```

main.ts:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [1, 2, 3];
```

I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`. It looks like file is not transpiled by SystemJS.

When I add import statement in first line it works perfectly:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'; // or any other package

let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [1, 2, 3];
```

It looks like SystemJS recognizes typescript file by "contents" - is this correct? If yes, how to force it to transpile every *.ts or src/* file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suspected, the systemjs guessing which syntax you are using in your file. You can help the systemjs by adding

```
// maybe you need to use " format:'register' " instead
System.config({
  meta: {
    '*.ts': {
      format: 'es6'
    }
  }
});
```

more info [module-formats](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md)

Comment: thx. i am aware of that option and t's useful for external libs but writing this for every file/class (>100) in an app does not makes sense (makes whole idea of dynamic loading irrelevant). specially when I know that in src/ dir are only *.ts files producing es6 modules.
I would like sth on package level not module like - 

System.config({
  meta: {
    './src': {
      format: 'es6'
    }
  }
});

OR extension level config - System.config({
  meta: {
    '*.ts': {
      format: 'es6'
    }
  }
});

Comment: you can use matching syntax if you need. './src/*.ts': { format: 'es6 }

Comment: I did not notice that - probably cliked by mistake while checking it as an answer. Sorry for that (IF that was me)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module to help out with handling multiple file extensions with SystemJS:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/one-plugin