# Systemjs and tsc setup - *.ts.js 404 (Not Found) Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, tsc, systemjs-builder

I was just trying to create proof-of-concept TS + SystemJS project with minimum possible setup - without "Angular2 starter kit" and such.
I've spent an hour googling and tweaking this setup but it still doesn't work.

I have the following setup:

```
/src/
 - model.ts
 - bootstrap.ts

/dist/

tsconfig.json
system.config.js
index.html
```

My **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "outDir": "./dist/"
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

My **SystemJS config**

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
        testapp: './src'
    },
    baseURL: './src',
    packages: {
        testapp: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },

});
```

My **index.html**

```
  <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('bootstrap.ts')
        .then(function(app) {
            console.log('app bootstrap success!');
        }, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

In the end **I have following error in console:**

```
system.src.js:1051 GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/src/bootstrap.ts.js 404 (Not Found)fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051....
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
```

I run `tsc -w` in one terminal tab and simple https server in the other.

Apparently - SystemJS wants to consume files with **.ts.js** extension while tsc generates .js and source maps but **NOT .ts.js**.

Do I miss `webpack` or `gulp` to do some part of the job? I thought SystemJS and `tsc` could do the bundling and transpiling but apparently there's smth missing in the build process.
Explanation on the SystemJS setup rather than fixing the bug would be also very helpful.

Comment: System.js doesn't know which transpiler to use because you haven't specified one in its configuration. Refer to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032390/how-to-make-systemjs-transpile-typescript-based-on-file-extension-not-contents)

Comment: Why do you do `System.import('bootstrap.ts')` and not `System.import('bootstrap.js')`?

Answer (score 0):

Setup can be fixed by following:

1) as [@Nitzan Tommer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942852/nitzan-tomer) mentioned - change **.ts to .js in System.import** block

```
index.html: System.import('bootstrap.js')
```

2) **(SystemJS) require is not defined** error is fixed by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730010/angular2-5-minute-install-bug-require-is-not-defined) - 
change tsconfig.json to have "system" as modules

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
//..
```

Here is the demo repo I've created with this setup: https://github.com/shershen08/systemjs-typescript-simple